# Is it a good idea to add a table with only one column (an auto incremented identity)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, localization

I'm developing a multilingual web application and I'm having some difficulties deciding what would be the best way to handle a particular scenario in the database (SQL Server 2008).

Let's say users can add posts. A post has default data and localized data. A post is also associated with exactly one category. The users can also manage these localized categories.

The part about the posts is pretty clear to me. That will be something like this:

```
Posts
-----
PostId (auto incremented identity)
CategoryId
CreationDate
SortOrder

PostLocalizations
-----------------
PostId
LanguageId
Title
Content
```

The problem I have is that a category has no default data. It's just a textual description and I'm not sure what would be the best way to store the localizations.

I can think of a possible solution, but I don't really like it.

```
Categories
----------
CategoryId (auto incremented identity)

CategoryLocalizations
---------------------
CategoryId
LanguageId
Name
```

I don't like that table with just one column: an auto incremented identity. Of course I can add dummy fields I don't really need like CreationDate or SortOrder, but that just seems silly.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: SQL Server 2008, as mentioned in the first sentence :-)

Comment: I would put a fallback/default `Name` in the `Categories` table, in case the appropriate localized value doesn't exist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

In pure relational design, the category here would be an attribute and not an entity. A table is an entity, a column is an attribute.  What you're really saying is that the CategoryLocalizations entity instances have a similar "Category", much as a group of books have a similar "colour" on the cover.  Except colour is finite and categories are continually made up (hence the identity).

This gap has long been identified and finally plugged in SQL Server 2012.  In SQL Server 2008 however, IDENTITY's normally the robust vehicle for high-volume transactional tables.  **However**, because your table looks to be very low volume, I would simple add that as a field in my configuration or generic settings table and update when I *infrequently* need a value, e.g.

```
declare @CategoryID int;
update config set @CategoryID = CategoryID = CategoryID + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Paul's suggestion of SEQUENCES is proper.

A silly way was using transaction (+ store procedure) and get MAX(CategoryId)+1 as the new ID when you're going to insert a new Category into the table.

When you add a new Language of an existing Category, you'll recall the existing CategoryId to re-use. UNIQUE KEY (CategoryId, LangaugeId) is also recommended to avoid careless mistake.

Comment: But what about the FK relation between Posts and (in this case) CategoryLocalizations? The field CategoryId in Posts will then point to multiple entries in CategoryLocalizations.